# build oculus 360 video player in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, video-player

I'm trying to build a very simple 360 video player for the Oculus Rift in Unity.

I have a 360 video .mp4 file (which has played successfully in 3rd party Oculus 360 video players, so I know the Oculus can handle the quality of the video).

I want to make a sphere with the camera inside, and have the video play when the app starts. Very simple. But having a lot of trouble. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I've brought the video in and tried to add it to a Skybox material, with no success. I've also tried to of course simply set the video as the material for the sphere, which also hasn't worked. I'd imagine this is relatively easy but am having a lot of trouble...

Answer (score 1):

You might take the path of building a sphere; applying a MeshRenderer to the sphere; apply a material to the MeshRenderer for which the material has a shader attached;  the attached shader would then be constructed to allow for reflection to the inside.  The book "Unity Virtual Reality Projects" by Jonathan Linowes explains this.  And it works.
You might run into a problem if the video texture is larger than 4096 pixels in one direction.  Unity has this limit.  Another point that you must consider is that the texture that you use to paint in Unity must be compatible with the video -- BGRA (video) to RGBA (unity) for instance.

All this can be handled by writing your own DLL for which you apply the video to the Unity texture through DirectX for instance. Unity has provided examples for writing C++ DLL for which one writes to a Unity texture through DirectX or OpenGL.  This is not a simple step -- but is quite doable.